# LibUsb.open error (Device Collission with Root hub)

Tags: java, usb, usb4java

Code Snippet

```
deviceHandle = new DeviceHandle();
int isDeviceOpened = LibUsb.open(device, deviceHandle);
```

Output:

```
isDeviceOpened: -12
```

Errors:

```
libusb: error [init_device] program assertion failed: device address collision with root hub

org.usb4java.LibUsbException: USB error 12: Unable to open USB device: Operation not supported or unimplemented on this platform

libusb: error [winusbx_open] could not open device \\.\USB<some chars here> #{some chars here} (interface 0): [5] Access is denied.
```

I already updated the driver using Zadig and I still encounter this.
Anything else to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be that I did not trigger LibUsb.freeDeviceList(devs, unref_devices); , I figured it out when I disconnected the USB device manually and successfully connected it when it is freshly connected.